# ltablex inside environment throws \end -error

Tags: environments, tabularx, ltablex

I wanted to use a `tabularx` (`ltablex` package) inside an environment, but there is an error (but it still builds okay).

I'm using `ltablex`, because I want a `longtable` spanning several pages with the behaviour of `tabularx` (having one or more columns auto-size via "X").

The example is a stripped down minimal version to show the error (for this simple example I wouldn't bother to create a new environment, the real thing has more formatting).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ltablex} % includes tabularx, but combined with longtables (spanning multiple pages)

\newenvironment{deftable}{
   \tabularx{\textwidth}{ |p{5cm}|X| }
}{
   \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}

\begin{deftable}
  cell & anothercell \\ \hline
  more cells & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren \\
\end{deftable}

\end{document}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{deftable} on input line 13 ended by \end{tabularx}.
```

I think the `tabularx` processor does not consume the `\end{tabularx}` that is put on the stack by `\endtabularx` ... but seriously, I know LaTeX not good enough to figure out some solution.

Comment: I get no error if I replace `\end{tabularx}` in the definition of `\TX@endtabularx` with `\endtabularx\endgroup`, but I'm not sure if this really solves the problem.

Comment: thx for cleaning my question, I'll remember this formatting for future questions. :) @cgnieder

Comment: @Faldrian no worries: you'll get used to this :) we all did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get no error if I replace `\end{tabularx}` (which is probably wrong in the first place) with `\endtabularx\endgroup`. No guarantee this won't break anything else.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ltablex} % includes tabularx, but combined with longtables (spanning multiple pages)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% get rid of \par (there are two empty lines in the definition by ltablex)
\patchcmd{\TX@endtabularx}{\par}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TX@endtabularx}{\par}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\TX@endtabularx}
  {\end{tabularx}}
  {\endtabularx\endgroup}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{deftable}{%
   \tabularx{\textwidth}{ |p{5cm}|X| }%
}{%
   \endtabularx
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The last patchcmd fixes it, probably by using endgroup to tell the parser this tabularx is finished now. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a try with `environ` package. But I am not sure if it works for your complex cases. It is worth giving a try. The following code works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ltablex} % includes tabularx, but combined with longtables (spanning multiple pages)
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{deftable}{%
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |p{5cm}|X| }%
    \BODY
   \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{deftable}
  cell & anothercell \\ \hline
  more cells & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren \\
\end{deftable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, the environ package produces very readable code. :)